# Combinations of M elements from N with non consecutive repetitions

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, recursion, combinatorics

I have the following problem which can be summarized as follows:

> Imagine you have two integers greater than 0, N (which defines the
>   array `n=np.array(range(N)`) and M. We'd like to generate all the
>   possible **combinations of elements** **of** **`n`** **with length
>   M**, with the condition that **no equal elements are consecutive**.

For example, for N=3 (`n=[0,1,2]`) and M=3 we should obtain:

```
(0,1,0), (0,1,2) (0,2,0), (0,2,1), (1,0,1), (1,0,2), (1,2,0), (1,2,1), (2,0,1), (2,0,2), (2,1,0), (2,1,2)
```

That is, combinations such as `(0,0,1), (1,1,1), (2,1,1)`...etc, don't have to appear. 
Note that the number of all the valid combinations is simply given by `N*(N-1)**(M-1)`.

As of now, for such example I am using this simple script (which also calculates all the combinations of varying length from m=1 to m=M):

```
import numpy as np
N = 3
M = 3
p = np.array(range(N))  

ic = [0]*M
c2 = np.zeros((int(N*(N-1)**(M-1)),M))
c1 = np.zeros((int(N*(N-1)**(M-2)),M-1))
c0 = np.zeros((int(N*(N-1)**(M-3)),M-2))
for i in p:
    c0[ic[0],:] = [i]
    ic[0] += 1
    for j in p[p!=i]:
        c1[ic[1],:] = [i,j]
        ic[1] += 1
        for k in p[p!=j]:
            c2[ic[2],:] = [i,j,k]
            ic[2] += 1
```

The problem is that this only works for this specific case with M=3, and M can be any integer greater than 0. So for some M, the previous code should have M nested loops which would have to be manually introduced.

I've tried defining a **recursive** function of variable number of loops, like this one that calculates the *number* of combinations (the number given by the equation above):

```
def rec_f(c,N,M):   
    if n>=1:
        for x in range(N):             
            c=rec_f(c,N,M-1)
    else:
        c += 1            
    return c
```

which I don't really even know why it works for that simple problem. Now, the thing is that I need to know the indices of the previous loops to be able replicate the script that generates all the possible combinations and I don't know how to that.

I've also tried to make one unique `for` loop (that would iterate N*(N-1)^(M-1) times), having in mind that the combinations can be expressed as numbers in base N, but after playing around for some time I got nothing useful.

I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance (and sorry for the long post)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the last element (if any) as an optional parameter to your recursive function. Also, no need for the `N` parameter, just pass the elements to chose from (also makes it more generally applicable). Also, I would recomment making it a generator function as the number of combinations might grow rather large, so you can consume them one by one as they come.

```
def combinations(elements, m, last=-1):
    if m:
        for x in elements:
            if x != last:
                for rest in combinations(elements, m-1, x):
                    yield (x,) + rest
    else:
        yield ()
```

Or a bit more compact, with `yield from` a generator expression:

```
def combinations(elements, m, last=-1):
    if m:
        yield from ((x,) + rest for x in elements if x != last
                                for rest in combinations(elements, m-1, x))
    else:
        yield ()
```

Example results, for both versions:

```
print(*combinations(range(3), 3))
# (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is achievable by using Python's (powerful) `itertools` library and then filtering out based on your condition. But what you want are rather the *product* and not *combination* of the array.

Here's one way to do it, assuming arguments N and M.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

p = np.arange(N)
```

Obtain the products of length 3:

```
product_iterator = itertools.product(p, repeat=M)
```

This gives you an iterator object. You can get a concrete list from it (and immediately turn it into an array, in this example, although I called it a list):

```
product_list = np.array(list(product_iterator))
```

At this point you got an array of all 27 combinations:  [ [0 0 0],  [0 0 1],  [0 0 2], ..., [2 2 1],  [2 2 2] ]. Now you can filter these by the criteria desired.

In your case, 'no repeated elements consecutive' amounts to checking if the difference between two consecutive elements is never zero. So we get the differences:

```
diffs = np.diff(product_list,axis=1)
```

This yields:

```
[[ 0  0]
 [ 0  1]
 [ 0  2]
 [ 1 -1]
 [ 1  0]
 [ 1  1]
 [ 2 -2]
 [ 2 -1]
 [ 2  0]
 [-1  0]
 [-1  1]
 [-1  2]
 [ 0 -1]
 [ 0  0]
 [ 0  1]
 [ 1 -2]
 [ 1 -1]
 [ 1  0]
 [-2  0]
 [-2  1]
 [-2  2]
 [-1 -1]
 [-1  0]
 [-1  1]
 [ 0 -2]
 [ 0 -1]
 [ 0  0]]
```

And now we check, row by row, if there are any zeroes:

```
no_consec_indexes = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.all(x), 1, diffs)
```

This yiels an array of booleans `no_consec_indexes`:

```
array([False, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,
       False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True, False,
       False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False, False])
```

You can use it to filter out the original product array:

```
product_list[no_consec_indexes]
```

Which yields your desired answer:

```
 array([[0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 2],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the highly detailed answer, I really appreciate it. Although to be honest I was aware of this possibility, but I dismissed it because I supposed the execution time would be too long. Now that several methods have been proposed I will try and see how they perform with respect each other.